# how to create two dimensional Array of type bool in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a `matrix` kind `datagrid` in my WPF application and 
I would like to create a two dimensional `Array` to access the row and column of the `datagrid`. how to access the datagridcells using 2-dimensional arrays of type bool, since my result will be of type Boolean.

for each [i][j] of this 10 x 10 rows, column array, I have to query

for example

```
[0][0] = result of one query

[0][1] = result of another query
```

**EDIT**

What I have tried

```
bool[,] cell = new bool[10, 10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j= 0; j<10 ;j++)
            {
            cell[i,j] = (); // what to write here 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your headers are of type `bool` ?

Comment: yes. i will edit the question now

Comment: I didn't get a whole lot clearer.

Comment: To rescue this question: add details, don't remove them.

Comment: _what to write here_ : `cell[i,j] = true;` or `cell[i,j] = false;` or maybe `cell[i,j] = MyBooleanFunction(i,j);`. We really can't make much more of the question.

Comment: MyBooleanFunction(i,j) sounds good. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
bool[,] array = new bool[1, 3];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: the array is for bool type.

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2D arrays in C#:

```
var array2D = new int[13, 100];
array2D[7, 11] = 48;
```